# What is the complexity of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Does the following algorithm have a complexity of O(nlogn)?

The thing that confuses me is that this algorithm divides twice, not once as a regular O(nlogn) algorithm, and each time it does O(n) work.

```
def equivalent(a, b):

    if isEqual(a, b):
        return True

    half = int(len(a) / 2)
    if 2*half != len(a):
        return False

    if (equivalent(a[:half], b[:half]) and equivalent(a[half:], b[half:])):
        return True

    if (equivalent(a[:half], b[half:]) and equivalent(a[half:], b[:half])):
        return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of the 4 recursive calls to `equivalent` reduces the amount of input data by a factor of 2. Thus, assuming that `a` and `b` have the same length, and `isEqual` has linear time complexity, we can construct the *recurrence relation* for the overall complexity:

[image]

Where `C` is some constant. We can solve this relation by repeatedly substituting and spotting a pattern:

[image]

What is the upper limit of the summation, `m`? The stopping condition occurs when `len(a)` is *odd*. That may be anywhere between `N` and `1`, depending on the *prime decomposition* of `N`. In the worse case scenario, `N` is a power of 2, so the function recurses until `len(a) = 1`, i.e.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, could you give me a reference to learn how to find the comlexity

Comment: @ayman for recursive functions the first step is always to find the recurrence relation. Once you have that you can make a range of different substitutions. If the relation is of the form `T(n) =
aT(n/b) + f(n)`, which is surprisingly common, then you can use the *master theorem*.

Answer (score 2):

To enhance the above answer, there is a direct way to calculate with 'Master Method'. The master method works only for following type of recurrences.

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n) where a >= 1 and b > 1
```

We have three cases based on the f(n) as below and reduction for them:

1. If f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>) where c < Log<sub>b</sub>a then T(n) = Θ(n <sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)
2. If f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>) where c = Log<sub>b</sub>a then T(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup> Log n)
3. If f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>) where c > Log<sub>b</sub>a then T(n) = Θ(f(n)) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>)

In your case,

we have a = 4, b = 2, c = 1 and c < Log<sub>b</sub>a

i.e. 1 < log<sub>2</sub>4

Hence => case 1

Therefore:
T(n) = Θ(n<sup>Log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)

T(n) = Θ(n<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>4</sup>)

**T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)**

More details with examples can be found in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Hope it helps!